# Flutter list not update after do change the list

Tags: flutter, listview

I have list data and try to change the value in position `[0]` to be value 5.

```
List<String> imagesVal = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
```

Then I have change function

```
void changeImage(id, file, mediaID) {
    setState(() {
        imagesVal[0] = '5';
    })

    print(imagesVal);
});
```

The result is: `['5', '2', '3', '4']`

Then I have save button

```
Future _save() async {
    print(imagesVal);
});
```

When tap the button, I got result still old value: `['1', '2', '3', '4']`

My question, how to get the latest update value? On above example it should be get the value `['5', '2', '3', '4']`

Comment: Can you please post your full code

Answer (score 2):

You should have declared the list inside the build method of stateful widget by mistake. Please move it outside the build method.